# Jexcel in android producing empty file

Tags: android, jexcelapi

I am trying to use jexcel in my Android app to write excel file. I opened workbook, created a sheet, wrote a label and that's it

An xls file is created but it is empty. I am not getting any errors. Anyone has it working or know why

EDIT: Here is the code

```
wbSettings.setUseTemporaryFileDuringWrite(true);   
File wbfile = new File("try.xls");
WritableWorkbook wb = null;

try{
wb = Workbook.createWorkbook(wbfile,wbSettings); 
WritableSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("hello", 0);
Label newCell = new Label(0,3,"testtt");
sheet.addCell(newCell);
}catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Well. No errors mean there is nothing to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I have do wb.write() and wb.close() at the end.